# Does Oracle DB has a tool like DTS Wizard in SQL Server?

Tags: database, oracle, import, csv, sql-server

Is there a tool like the Microsoft SQL Server's DTS (Data Transformation Services) Wizard that simplifies the process of ad-hoc importing of flat files (CSV, TSV, or XLS) to Oracle database?

Preferably free ones or the ones that are licensed together with the database.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Oracle Warehouse Builder](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/warehouse/overview/introduction/index.html) is the standard Oracle ETL tool that comes with the database.

> OWB 11gR2 is pre-installed with Oracle Database 11gR2, and can be installed and used alongside Oracle Database 10gR2 and 11gR1.

Regarding licensing, you might want to check with Oracle but it looks like you can use the ETL features with the database license:

> The Oracle Database license permits the use of OWB basic ETL features.